# Filter pandas dataframe rows containing non-ascii values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-3.6, non-ascii-characters

I have a column with addresses and want to find all rows that contain 'foreign' i.e. non-ASCII characters.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
    'column_name': ["GREENLAND HOTEL, CENTRAL AVENUE, NAGPUR-440 018.", "Møllegade 1234567 DK-6400 Sønderborg Denmark"],
    'column_other': ["0", "1"]
})
```

Expected output is it will display only the 2nd row which contains the "ø" character.

I tried this:

```
df['column_name'].str.isascii()
```

but in Python 3.6 at least this does not work.

In MySQL I can do this equivalent

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE `column_name`!=CONVERT(`column_name` USING ASCII)
```

which works.

Comment: @anky_91 Great suggestion. I added a test case dataframe with one row that should match and one that shouldn't.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about the performance, but you can try to `encode` the string and `ignore` the errors, then compare the `len` of the encoded string to the original one like:

```
mask_nonAscii = df.column_name.map(lambda x: len(x.encode('ascii', errors='ignore')) != len(x))
print (df[mask_nonAscii])
                                    column_name column_other
1  Møllegade 1234567 DK-6400 Sønderborg Denmark            1
```

---

EDIT: thanks to a comment of [anky_91](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9840637/anky-91) you can also use `str.len` and `str.encode` from pandas like:

```
mask_nonAscii = df['column_name'].str.len()\
                 .ne(df['column_name'].str.encode('ascii',errors = 'ignore').str.len())
```

at least the comparison between lengths is vectorize

---

Also, I have not seen any documentation about a method in `pandas.Series.str.isascii`, but if you use python 3.7+, maybe you can create the mask this way:

```
mask_nonAscii = ~df.column_name.map(str.isascii)
```

Answer (score 1):

In this example, the dataframe is named `data`

1. First of all make a list of columns of string datatype

   `cols = ["A", "B", "C"]`
2. Run the code below to loop through the columns to state the number of values in each column that have the non-ascii characters

```
for col in cols:    
    print(col, data[col].str.len().ne(data[col].str.encode("ascii", errors="ignore").str.len()).sum())

A 0
B 3
C 0
```

For this example, column `B` has the non-ascii values

3. Run the modified code below to get the rows with the non-ascii values

   `data["B"].str.len().ne(data["B"].str.encode("ascii", errors="ignore").str.len())`